# check if tree if complete binary search tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-search-tree

I'am learning about trees. I just completed problem to check if tree is complete BST or not. I'd like to know if i did it right. 
Basically i just have to look for a node which has only one child, for the whole tree.

EDIT: I had definition of both complete and full binary search tree wrong as Mooing Duck pointed out. I finished coding it now, is this the solution?

```
    int heightBST(Node* root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    int lHeight = heightBST(root->left);    
    int rHeight = heightBST(root->right);
    return lHeight > rHeight ? 1 + lHeight : 1 + rHeight;
}

int isFullBST(Node* root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    int lHeight = heightBST(root->left);
    int rHeight = heightBST(root->right);
    if (lHeight != rHeight)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if ((root->left == NULL && root->right != NULL) || (root->left != NULL && root->right == NULL))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (isCompleteBST(root->left) == 0 || isCompleteBST(root->right) == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int isCompleteBST(Node* root)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    int lHeight = heightBST(root->left);
    int rHeight = heightBST(root->right);
    if (lHeight - rHeight != 0 || lHeight - rHeight != 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if ((root->left == NULL && root->right != NULL) || (root->left != NULL && root->right == NULL))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (isCompleteST(root->left) == 0 || isCompleteBST(root->right) == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: According to  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree, all children having 2 or 0 children is a "full" tree, not complete.  In a complete binary tree every level, except possibly the last, is completely filled, and all nodes in the last level are as far left as possible.

Comment: The left and right subtrees must also have the same height.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. So for this code i need to add height check for every node and i get code for verification of full BST, right? For complete BST code i will have to think first what to do since there is the case where left height is bigger and it's a valid one